# Azure Registered App Keys

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

In Azure Active Directory, when one registers an application they can create API access keys for that application. Is it possible for a registered application to know when its own key expires by using some Azure sdk call? I'm looking to notify users that their key is soon to expire, if they chose for it to expire.

Comment: may be helpful https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2015/04/27/check-for-expired-azure-mobile-services-authentication-tokens/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to register an application and get the end date of application's key.

To achieve this, we need to grant the `Directory.Read.All` permission to the app. Then we can read the end date of application's key from application entity like request below:

```
GET: https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/applications/{applicationObjectId}?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {access_token}
```

Then you would get the response like below:

```
{
    passwordCredentials[
        {
            customKeyIdentifier='',
            endDate='2018-12-30T02:23:46.753Z',
            keyId='',
            startDate='2016-08-25T07:47:24.8878Z',
            value=null,
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

You can refer [application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference) entity for more detail.

### Update

Here is the figure for your reference to config the permission:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this is on the right track! I'm having some trouble granting this permission, would you be able to show me where it is in the portal? I've granted various permissions that look to be directory read access, but I am still getting an insufficient privileges error.

Comment: I have upload the figure, please let me know if you still have the problem